# Autoincrement application version in nodejs package with git push

Tags: node.js, git, npm, versioning

I'm struggling to find a way to auto increment my package.json of my node application. I've understand that npm has a script called `version` which accepts 3 params: minor,major and patch but I failed to use `npm version minor` for example to increment to a new version.

I get `npm ERR! Git working directory not clean` everytime I try to do it.

So what I want to do is the following:

1. I have a node app with a package.json file and the version of it start at 0.0.1.
2. Working on a new feature or bug fix or anything, then I'm creating a new branch and want to push my changes to git.
3. Now comes the struggling part:

At this point before the commit I guess I'll have to inrement the package json. How do I increment the value automatically when pushing to git?
As I said now it will be version 0.0.1 like :

```
{
  "name": "App name",
  "version": "0.0.1",
   ...
}
```

And with the new commit, let's say this is a minor release, it should be :

```
{
  "name": "App name",
  "version": "0.0.2",
   ...
}
```

Also this app will not be published on NPM package repository, so I won't need npm publish.

Comment: `npm version` is intended for publishing to npm, as you might already noticed and that is why it requires a clean state. Internally they are most likely using `semver`. You could probably create a git hook to do what you need but I would like to understand a little better why you need to do that. Git already provides you with a unique hash that could be used to get a specific version of your code.

Comment: Actually i just wanted my npm version to be sinc with github version tag, just for my interest. I've manage to do it just now and will post the solution soon. Thanks for helping thou

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all thank you for the help. 
Second the error I got was because I had uncommited files in the branch I was in. To fix that error, I've did `git add` and `git commit` before `npm version` and this steps let me use `npm version patch` command and increment the `package.json` file version to 0.0.2 how I wanted.
As @Erick Ruiz de Chavez pointed out in comments above `npm version` is indented to publish the package on npm but I've used it to sync my Github release version to the package version in the `package.json` with the help of `git push && git push --tags` command.

Answer (score 8):

Minor addition - you can just skip Git version tagging like so:

`npm version patch -git-tag-version false`

This will also work if you have uncommitted changes, and won't do anything but increment the version number in your `package.json`.

Answer (score 0):

Please check my [NodeAutoVersionPush](https://github.com/Sherbeeny/NodeAutoVersionPush) script.
It's a script using Visual Studio Code API to auto set the new version then do commit and push with a keyboard shortcut.

The new version is based on current date and total commits.
But you can easily tweak the code to your preference or for any other language.